# How do i make an object in canvas move based on it's x and y coordinates with a keyboard inputs?

Tags: javascript

this is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. I was wondering on to make an object move based on its x and y coordinates with keyboard inputs. I am making a grid based movement for my game. I apologize for any bad code or formatting. I am making a web game for a school project. Do comment if u need  my html code. Here's my code below:

```
 $(function(){
  var health = 800;
  var fuel = 100;
  var tankX = 25;
  var tankY = 530;

  var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
  ctx.fillRect(0,600,1110,100);
  ctx.stroke();

  for (i = 100; i < 600; i += 100) 
  {
     ctx.moveTo(0, i);
     ctx.lineTo(c.width, i);
     ctx.stroke();
  }

  for (i = 100; i < 1110; i += 100) 
  {
     ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
     ctx.lineTo(i,600);
     ctx.stroke();
  }

  ctx.fillStyle ="black";
  ctx.font = "20px  Lucida Sans Typewriter ";
  ctx.fillText("Health:",500,630);
  ctx.fillText("Fuel:", 100,630);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(500,640,(health/800)*250,40);

  function fuelGauge(){
   ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
   ctx.fillRect(100,640,(fuel/100)*250,40);
   console.log(fuel);
 }

 function drawTank(){
     ctx.fillStyle = "#283618"
     ctx.fillRect(tankX,tankY,50,50);
     ctx.moveTo(tankX,tankY);
 }

 drawTank();
 fuelGauge();
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't do a lot of jquery, but since nobody answered, here's an example. It uses the `keydown` event to listen for the arrow keys. I'm sure there's lots of room for improvement, but it should get you started.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var tankX = 25;
var tankY = 530;
var health = 800;
var fuel = 100;

$('html').keydown(function(e){
  eraseTank();

  if (e.key == "ArrowUp") {
    if (tankY > 15) tankY -= 102;
  }
  else if (e.key == "ArrowDown") {
    if (tankY < 530) tankY += 102;
  }
  else if (e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    if (tankX > 25) tankX -= 100;
  }
  else if (e.key == "ArrowRight") {
    if (tankX < 525) tankX += 100;
  }

  drawTank();
});

function fuelGauge(){
 ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
 ctx.fillRect(100,640,(fuel/100)*250,40);
 console.log(fuel);
}

function drawTank(){
   ctx.fillStyle = "#283618"
   ctx.fillRect(tankX,tankY,50,50);
   ctx.moveTo(tankX,tankY);
}
function eraseTank(){
   ctx.fillStyle = "white"
   ctx.fillRect(tankX,tankY,50,50);
   ctx.moveTo(tankX,tankY);
}

function drawGame()
{
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
  ctx.fillRect(0,600,1110,100);
  ctx.stroke();

  for (i = 100; i < 600; i += 100) 
  {
     ctx.moveTo(0, i);
     ctx.lineTo(c.width, i);
     ctx.stroke();
  }

  for (i = 100; i < 1110; i += 100) 
  {
     ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
     ctx.lineTo(i,600);
     ctx.stroke();
  }

  ctx.fillStyle ="black";
  ctx.font = "20px  Lucida Sans Typewriter ";
  ctx.fillText("Health:",500,630);
  ctx.fillText("Fuel:", 100,630);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(500,640,(health/800)*250,40);
}

$(function(){
  drawGame();
  fuelGauge();
  drawTank();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="600" height="1100"></canvas>
```

When you run the snippet, make sure you click on the game board first.